# log errors in celery to django-sentry

Tags: django, celery, sentry

How would I log errors to django-sentry from celery tasks?

I've tried try: except: blocks and using raven_client.create_from_exception but that blows up every time with:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 47, in trace
        return cls(states.SUCCESS, retval=fun(*args, **kwargs))
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/task/__init__.py", line 247, in __call__
        return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 175, in run
        return fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/controlpanel/deployments/1323265958/src/deploy/tasks.py", line 60, in async_deploy_bundle
        raven_client.create_from_exception(exc_info=exc_info)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/__init__.py", line 120, in create_from_exception
        return super(DjangoClient, self).create_from_exception(exc_info, **kwargs)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/base.py", line 285, in create_from_exception
        frames = varmap(shorten, get_stack_info(iter_traceback_frames(exc_traceback)))
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/stacks.py", line 128, in get_stack_info
        'vars': transform(frame.f_locals.items()),
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in transform
        ret = type(value)(transform_rec(o) for o in value)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in <genexpr>
        ret = type(value)(transform_rec(o) for o in value)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 72, in <lambda>
        transform_rec = lambda o: transform(o, stack + [value], context)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in transform
        ret = type(value)(transform_rec(o) for o in value)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in <genexpr>
        ret = type(value)(transform_rec(o) for o in value)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 72, in <lambda>
        transform_rec = lambda o: transform(o, stack + [value], context)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/raven/utils/encoding.py", line 78, in transform
        ret = type(value)(transform_rec(o) for o in value)
      File "/home/controlpanel/current/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/git/util.py", line 588, in __init__
        raise ValueError("First parameter must be a string identifying the name-property. Extend the list after initialization")
    ValueError: First parameter must be a string identifying the name-property. Extend the list after initialization
```

My task:

```
@task
def async_deploy_bundle(bundle_id):
    try:
        do_stuff(bundle_id)
    except:
        exc_info = sys.exc_info()
        traceback.print_exception(*exc_info)
        try:
            raven_client = get_client()
            raven_client.create_from_exception(exc_info=exc_info)
        except:
            pass
        raise
```

Comment: Could you post the line where you're calling `create_from_exception`?

Comment: Added my task to the question

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
    myLogger = logging.getLogger('mylogger.info')
    myLogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    myLogger.info(exc_info)
```

?

In my settings.py:

```
'loggers': {
    'mylogger.info': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
        'propagate': False,
        },
           }
```